# Annoying see-through task bar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

I am forced to use Windows at work. I think it is Windows 8 Professional. One annoyance is that the task bar is see through as follows:

[image]

As you can see, an application is visible underneath the task bar. I find this distracting and annoying. I tried using the context menu from the task bar and it appeared to have no setting to control this transparency. How can I make the task bar fully opaque?

Comment: That's probably a theme setting. On Windows 7, I'd say it's Aero Glass, but I know that that theme doesn't exist on Windows 8 or Windows 10.

Comment: So I don't have access to windows 8. But try right clicking on the desktop and select personalize, then on the left select 'Colors' and there may be an option in there, like 'Make the taskbar and action center transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't without 3rd party software, but there is a work around!

1. Open regedit
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`
3. Add a **DWORD** called `ColorizationOpaqueBlend` with the value of `0`
4. Restart your computer

**Backup the registry before trying this, because you could screw up your pc.**

Comment: If there is a work around, that means, third-party software isn't required.

Comment: @Ramhound It isn't. regedit comes with windows

Comment: So don't say it isn't possible then?

Comment: I mean there isn't a one-click setting to do it @Ramhound

Comment: It's a workaround @Ramhound